# How to select rows with condition via concat?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause, concatenation

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',NAME, SURNAME, 'was born in', DATE_FORMAT(BIRTHDAY,'%Y')) AS RESULT 
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE KURS == 1 OR KURS == 2;
```

I need only those rows where the column KURS contains '1' or '2'

```
SELECTS * FROM STUDENTS
```

[image: SELECTS * FROM STUDENTS]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `==` operator in MySQL. Presumably, you mean:

```
WHERE KURS = 1 OR KURS = 2
```

Which can be simplified as:

```
WHERE KURS IN (1, 2)
```

The `SELECT` clause looks fine and should work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

create a sub select like this may works:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',NAME, SURNAME, 'was born in', DATE_FORMAT(BIRTHDAY,'%Y')) AS RESULT 
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE KURS == 1 OR KURS == 2) AS Query
WHERE KURS = 1
```

Comment: Hi Douglas. To make more readable your answer you can create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~ . You can take a look  at [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)